# Type conversion in dataframe using mask and error/incompatibilities

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, mask

I have such dataframe whose element I want to convert to sets for those which are string or lists, and replace with an empty set for those which are None.

```
    id  super_graph sub_graph
GO1 GO1 ['GO4', 'GO5', 'GO6', 'GO7', 'GO8', 'GO9']  GO9
GO2 GO2 ['GO4', 'GO5', 'GO6', 'GO7', 'GO8', 'GO9']  GO11
GO3 GO3 ['GO1', 'GO5', 'GO6', 'GO7', 'GO8', 'GO9']  GO12
GO4 GO4 ['GO1', 'GO6', 'GO7']   
GO5 GO5 ['GO5'] 
GO6 GO6 ['GO1', 'GO5', 'GO7', 'GO3', 'GO9'] 
GO7 GO7 ['GO2', 'GO5', 'GO6', 'GO7', 'GO8', 'GO10', 'GO11', 'GO12'] 
GO8 GO8 ['GO2', 'GO3', 'GO4', 'GO5', 'GO6', 'GO7', 'GO8', 'GO9']    
GO9 GO9
```

I managed to do that in two steps; converting in lists the strings, then converting those lists to steps using them:

```
initial_frame = count_frame.loc[:,['id', "super_graph", "sub_graph"]]#THE FRAME WHOSE EXAMPLE YOU HAVE ABOVE
initial_frame_mask =  ~initial_frame.applymap(lambda cell: isinstance(cell, list)| (cell is None))

list_frame = initial_frame.mask(initial_frame_mask,initial_frame.applymap(lambda l: [l]))
list_frame2 = list_frame.applymap(lambda l: set(l) if l is not None else {})
```

The trick is here to use the [] list constructor (maybe I should not use this word which has a very specific meaning in the languages but I can't find any better) instead of list(l) in list_frame creation as they behave differently, [] will take a string as such, list() will break down string sequences to their parts.

Then I convert these lists using the set() method, and conditional expression for avoiding including None (the end goal being to add all three lists for each row of the columns (Maybe I could use better methods, don't know, but anyway, I want to answer to the question that's following, for personal edification)

I actually intended to do this in one step, using  code as follow:

```
initial_frame = count_frame.loc[:,['id', "super_graph", "sub_graph"]] 
initial_frame_mask =  ~initial_frame.applymap(lambda cell: isinstance(cell, list))

list_frame = initial_frame.mask(initial_frame_mask,initial_frame.applymap(lambda l: {l}) if l is not None else {})
```

but Python won't let me do like I want:)
actually set() method accepts lists and strings, behaving like the list() method toward them. I thus intended to use {} to do that but it don't work; throwing this exception:

```
list_frame = initial_frame.mask(initial_frame_mask,initial_frame.applymap(lambda l: {l} if l is not None else {}))

TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index super_graph')
```

It is exactly as doing

```
In [354]: l=[1,2]
In [355]: {l}
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-355-37b01148d270>", line 1, in <module>
    {l}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So I believe the mask method selects the data after performing the vectorized operation on the whole, but thus, this triggers this error that I should not actually see since my initial_frame_mask is well tailored to avoid the inconvenient values.

```
    id  super_graph sub_graph
GO1 True    False   True
GO2 True    False   True
GO3 True    False   True
GO4 True    False   False
GO5 True    False   False
GO6 True    False   False
GO7 True    False   False
GO8 True    False   False
GO9 True    False   False
```

So I would like to know how I can do this in one step (maybe using a similar function, that does not behave like mask but avoid to begin with the bad values, or using another way to convert this).
I also would like to know why list and [] behave so differently, I did not see anything in Python docs explaining this is intended, and idem for set() and {}.
Thanks by advance.

Quicknote: indeed: list_frame2 = list_frame.applymap(lambda l: set(l) if l is not None else {}) won't work, as it outputs

```
id super_graph sub_graph
GO1  {GO1}       {nan}     {GO9}
GO2  {GO2}       {nan}    {GO11}
GO3  {GO3}       {nan}    {GO12}
GO4  {GO4}       {nan}     {nan}
GO5  {GO5}       {nan}     {nan}
GO6  {GO6}       {nan}     {nan}
GO7  {GO7}       {nan}     {nan}
GO8  {GO8}       {nan}     {nan}
GO9  {GO9}       {nan}     {nan}
```

Edit: dataframe generator (but I think there is a command from clipboard to do that, that's why I did not included it at first, sorry;

```
count_frame = pd.DataFrame([["GO2","GO3","GO4","GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO9"],\
[["GO4", "GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO9"],
["GO4", "GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO9"],
["GO1", "GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO9"],
["GO1", "GO6","GO7"],
["GO5"]
["GO1", "GO5","GO7","GO3","GO9"],
["GO2", "GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO10","GO11", "GO12"],
["GO2", "GO3","GO4","GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO9"],
],\
["GO9","GO11","GO12"]], index = ['id','super_graph','sub_graph'], columns=["GO1","GO2","GO3","GO4","GO5","GO6","GO7","GO8","GO9","]).T
```

Comment: Can you provide a way of generating the input dataframe? It's not clear what the `dtypes` are.

Comment: Have you tried using `{*l}` instead of just `{l}` ?

Comment: That would be a good call, but it will break apart the strings. Anyway, I ended up proceeding with the lists, then summing these then converting these to sets (I had a mistake for the None conditional as using if None then {} replace None with dicts, but anyway writing if None then set() doesn't change anything and sum doesn't work well with sets...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the masking step and go straight to the mapping.

Actually, by introducing the following line, I feel that you create your own problem.

```
initial_frame_mask =  ~initial_frame.applymap(lambda cell: isinstance(cell, list))
```

This introduces a mask which is False for all lists, so for pretty much all elements of `super_graph`, but what happens for other elements is not completely transparent.

To achieve what you seem to want, in one line of code:

```
initial_frame = count_frame.loc[:,['id', "super_graph", "sub_graph"]] 
initial_frame.applymap(lambda l: {*l} if isinstance(l, list) else {l})
```

EDIT: if you do not wish for the "None" to appear in your dataframe, you can first replace those values with a convenient one.

```
initial_frame.fillna('').applymap(lambda l: {*l} if isinstance(l, list) else {l})
```

EDIT2: Hacky solution to getting the lists with unique items (could also do it as oneliner, but figured this is already convoluted enough):

```
initial_frame['ss'] = initial_frame.fillna('').applymap(lambda l: [*l] if isinstance(l, list) else []).values.sum(axis=1)
initial_frame['ss'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(None,{*x})))
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't want to include None in sets as it will be tedious to eliminate them but I guess that I could achieve this with initial_frame.applymap(lambda l: {*l} if l is not Not else None if l isinstance(l, list) else {l}). plus anyway I became aware that I could not sum up the sets the way I do with the lists ( working_series = list_frame.sum(axis= 1)), so I do exactly this on the list then use    working_series.map(set) (else I have a sum of sets which is only floats, strangely, while it is all fine for lists). I will accept your answer anyway, since you did answer the problem

Comment: If you want to get rid of the Nones, you can do `initial_frame.fillna('')`. As for the sum over axis 1, that is likely to produce scary results along the lines of `{'GO3'}{` etc. or just float64s `0`.

Comment: Yeah, actually I got it wrong with the None part, I wanted to fillna with list but it was not possible, so I tried to replace them after (the string replacement did not occur to me, I was stupid about that, since I replaced strings anyway). For the summation part, I add no better call than summing lists, since with sets it doesn't work, and I want something flexible where I don't have to specify indexes or labels or looping or whatever. So I guess that with list, it should be ok? Won't unpacking each time might be less efficient performance wise than using a mask?

Comment: I guess that is a way to go; I am not quite sure about the outcome though; I edited again with what I think is you want, but it is quite a hacky solution which feels suboptimal..you can of course replace `list(filter(...))` with `set(filter(...))` or other iterables.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed filter could do this.